# Special characters problem when displaying directory contents with PHP

Tags: php, directory, display

I am attempting to simply display the contents of a directory using php, but it is not recognising certain french characters and apostrophes in the filenames therefore making the links unusable. Is this a charset defining issue or is what I'm asking it to do not possible? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.two-words.co.uk/aboutnapoleon/test/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./.favicon.ico">
   <title>Sources | About Napoleon</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./.style.css">
   <script src="./.sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <h1>Sources </h1>

 <table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Filename</th>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>Size</th>
   <th>Date Modified</th>
  </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody><?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 // Adds pretty filesizes
 function pretty_filesize($file) {
  $size=filesize($file);
  if($size<1024){$size=$size." Bytes";}
  elseif(($size<1048576)&&($size>1023)){$size=round($size/1024, 1)." KB";}
  elseif(($size<1073741824)&&($size>1048575)){$size=round($size/1048576, 1)." MB";}
  else{$size=round($size/1073741824, 1)." GB";}
  return $size;
 }

  // Checks to see if veiwing hidden files is enabled
 if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
 {$hide="";
  $ahref="./";
  $atext="Hide";}
 else
 {$hide=".";
  $ahref="./?hidden";
  $atext="Show";}

  // Opens directory
  $myDirectory=opendir(".");

 // Gets each entry
 while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[]=$entryName;
 }

 // Closes directory
 closedir($myDirectory);

 // Counts elements in array
 $indexCount=count($dirArray);

 // Sorts files
 sort($dirArray);

 // Loops through the array of files
 for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

 // Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
     if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1)!=$hide) {

 // Resets Variables
  $favicon="";
  $class="file";

 // Gets File Names
  $name=$dirArray[$index];
  $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

 // Gets Date Modified
  $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
  $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));


 // Separates directories, and performs operations on those directories
  if(is_dir($dirArray[$index]))
  {
    $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;";
    $size="&lt;Directory&gt;";
    $sizekey="0";
    $class="dir";

   // Gets favicon.ico, and displays it, only if it exists.
    if(file_exists("$namehref/favicon.ico"))
     {
      $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/favicon.ico);'";
      $extn="&lt;Website&gt;";
     }

   // Cleans up . and .. directories
    if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;"; $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/.favicon.ico);'";}
    if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
  }

 // File-only operations
  else{
   // Gets file extension
   $extn=pathinfo($dirArray[$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   // Prettifies file type
   switch ($extn){
    case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
    case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
    case "jpeg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
    case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
    case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
    case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;

    case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
    case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
    case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "html": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "xhtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "shtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
    case "js": $extn="Javascript File"; break;
    case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;

    case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;
    case "xls": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
    case "xlsx": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
    case "doc": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;
    case "docx": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;

    case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
    case "htaccess": $extn="Apache Config File"; break;
    case "exe": $extn="Windows Executable"; break;

    default: if($extn!=""){$extn=strtoupper($extn)." File";} else{$extn="Unknown";} break;
   }

   // Gets and cleans up file size
    $size=pretty_filesize($dirArray[$index]);
    $sizekey=filesize($dirArray[$index]);
  }

 // Output
  echo("
  <tr class='$class'>
   <td><a href='./$namehref'$favicon class='name'>$name</a></td>
   <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
  </tr>");
    }
 }
 ?>

     </tbody>
 </table>

 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).

Comment: Where do you set `$namehref`, `$extn`, `$sizekey`, etc.?

Comment: Use `urlencode()` to properly encode special characters in URL parameters.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding($name, 'utf-8', 'iso8859-1')` should also make the names display properly. Note: The source encoding might actually be `cp1252` if this is a Windows machine.

Comment: Apologies @Barmar, I am a novice, where should I use urlencode() ?

Comment: `$namehref = urlencode($dirArray[$index]);`

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't worked @Barman, it changed all the urls '%20' to + making the links unreachable.

Comment: @Sammitch, where should I put the ```mb_convert_encoding($name, 'utf-8', 'iso8859-1')``` and yes, it is a windows machine. Have I encoded the php file incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using IIS to host this PHP script?
If yes, maybe this problem can be solved changing some IIS configurations, following the instructions from this [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CannotOpenAFileHavingSpecialCharactersInTheFilenameOnIIS.html).

If possible, normalize the filenames in the server to a more legible way, like changing "space" to "_", "?" to "", "ç" to "c", and so on.

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcosAM, normalizing the filenames was the way forward. I used HTML entities for apostrophes and question marks, changed the charset=ISO-8859-1 and finally used ```urlencode()``` to properly encode special characters in URL parameters.